# Copying files to zfs mountpoint doesn't work - the files aren't actually copied to the other filesystem,

Tags: 12.04, 64-bit, zfs

I have 3 x 4 TB disks in a NAS that I want to group together and access as if they were one whole 'unit' of some kind.

I also have a 250GB disk containing the OS - this is full of films and tv shows currently.

I thought zfs sounded good so I created a raidz zpool, after installing the [ppa](https://launchpad.net/~zfs-native/+archive/stable)

```
sudo zpool create store raidz /dev/sdb /dev/sdc /dev/sdd
```

and set the mountpoint to /mnt/store

```
sudo zfs set mountpoint=/mnt/store /store
```

checked it was successful - I think it was

```
sudo zfs list
NAME USED AVAIL REFER MOUNTPOINT
store 266K 7.16T 170K /mnt/store
```

Then I wanted to move over a whole load of files from my home directory. I went to where the to-be-copied folder was (called media) and entered

```
sudo cp -R * /mnt/store
cp: cannot create directory `/mnt/store/media': No space left on device
```

It seems like it's not copying over to the new filesystem I made (or thought I did). I've never really done this type of thing until a few days ago so may be running before I can walk...

is this not the right way to copy files across? I've only used windows before so the idea of mountpoints is a bit mind boggling.

I'm using [XBMCbuntu 12](http://www.xbmcfreak.nl/en/xbmcbuntu-12-04-with-pre-frodo-mid-august-release/) beta 2.0 which is based on 12.04.
Will retry with normal Ubuntu 12.04 desktop to see if that's the problem.

thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I needed to enable auto mount boot

```
sudo nano /etc/default/zfs
```

set ZFS_MOUNT to YES